# search serialised meta_value for date value?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, array

i've saved and array of 'open days' as a serialised array in a meta value.

I was hoping i could then just search this field for the selected dates but i can't seem to create a match.

serialised = a:2:{i:0;s:10:"2011-09-16";i:1;s:10:"2011-09-17";} ; // two open dates

and was trying this and some variation without luck ;

```
$values_serialized = serialize(array('2011-09-16')); // need to serialise???

$args =  array ('meta_query' => array( 
    array( 'key'=>'v-openDays', 'value'=>$values_serialized,'compare'=>'IN' ) 
  )
)
// IN or LIKE?
```

will also be searching for multiple days but need to get one working first! Help appreciated, Dc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't serialize the search value, just use `'value' => '2011-09-16' 'compare' => 'LIKE'`.

Otherwise you're essentially looking for;

```
a:1:{i:0;s:10:"2011-09-16"}
```

Which of course doesn't actually match anywhere in;

```
a:2:{i:0;s:10:"2011-09-16";i:1;s:10:"2011-09-17";}
```

Comment: yeh - finally figured out that much and also IN had to be LIKE. Cheers!

Comment: @daniel nice one - updated answer for 'correctness' ;)